# Django filter: Finding a best practice

Tags: django, django-orm, django-filter

I am finding a way to achieve a filter in a fewer code like, my current filter working fine below:

```
if company == 1:
    unknownFood = food.filter(
        purchase__credit = 2
        company__name__isnull=True
    )
elif company == 2:
    unknownFood = food.filter(
        purchase__credit = 2
        company__name__isnull=False
    )
else:
    unknownFood = food.filter(
        purchase__credit = 2
    )
```

Above code, appeared with few repeated line of code and I believe this is not a best practice.

I am trying to achieve this with a fewer line code than above code.

here you go:

```
if company == 1:
    isNull = True
elif company == 2:
    isNull = False
else:
    pass

unknownFood = food.filter(
        purchase__credit = 2
        company__name__isnull=isNull
    )
```

if i do like above shortened way, it fires me an error, coz

`company__name__isnull` is equeal to `false` or `true` and its third block gets neither true or false

Can anyone suggest me the best way to achieve this?

Comment: If you have a working code and is looking for a code review, there is https://codereview.stackexchange.com/. Just make sure to check and follow their guidelines

Comment: Both code snippets you posted will raise a syntax error. Please paste actual code instead of a hypothetical one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can code it like this:

```
unknownFood = food.filter(purchase__credit=2)

if company == 1:
    unknownFood = unknownFood.filter(company__name__isnull=True)
elif company == 2:
    unknownFood = unknownFood.filter(company__name__isnull=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

in shortened code you write variable `isNull` can be undefiend and its cause exception in your code. you can fix this problem like this:

```
unknownFood = food.filter(purchase__credit = 2)

if company in [1,2]:
    unknownFood = unknownFood.filter(company__name__isnull=(company==1))
```